# PDF Structure, missing >>endobj

Tags: pdf

I Have a pdf file, that my java application considers as corrupt,

Logs point that the error is right before 'trailer'

[image]

I manually edited the PDF as following, my java app no longer considers the PDF as corrupt.

[image]

Does missing the `>> endobj` makes the PDF non-compliant to standards ?

**Update This is how the /content  613 line ends :**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately you don't show the complete line before the point of insertion, so we cannot tell whether that `>> endobj` really is completely missing or merely present with errors. That being said, though, the `>> endobj` is not the only thing missing there, right before the trailer the complete cross reference table is missing, so the PDF still definitively is broken.

Comment: The /content line was too long, I couldn't post it entirely, an update how the end of it looks.

Comment: That end indeed is interesting: The "0000 n" is a part of a cross reference entry while the data before quite likely does belong to th object 34. Thus, here is the exact position where a lot of content got lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last XRef section is indicated to be at offset 30279 before you made the change.
The insertion you made pushes the XRef section further down the file.
That means that after the insertion, this offset should reflect the new position.
You inserted at least 8 printable characters and two linebreaks, so at least 10 bytes, or 12, if using `\r\n` newlines instead.

So, yes, the change you made, without modifying the `startxref` indicator, technically leaves the file non-compliant. That said, from my experience, readers will often try to make sense of the file anyway (more or less quietly).

Regarding the input file: I think you have a broken object (34 0), where the dictionary is not terminated. The file is non-compliant already, based on what is visible/guessable from the screenshot. The fix you're attempting is the right thing to do.

This case would be trickier if you were not modifying the last object in the file. In that case, you would also be changing the offset of subsequent objects, and would have to reflect those changes in the corresponding XRef section.

Also watch out when editing PDFs in a text editor that you do not break binary contents (if there are any), which can happen just by saving the file. It's safer to do these things in a hex editor.

Comment: As you mention cross references - the pasted PDF content clearly has an explicit `trailer`. Thus, this PDF is not a pure cross reference stream file but a cross reference table or hybrid one. But in that case the cross reference table would have to be right before the trailer which it clearly is not! Thus, the remaining issue in the file is not merely that the **startxref** is off by a few bytes, also the cross reference table is completely amiss!

Comment: I noticed it's likely an appended-to PDF file (based on the pointer to the previous XRef section at 27013). I'm not familiar with the data that needs to be in the incremental XRef section. It seems it should at least include info about the newly-added objects.

Comment: Yes, indeed an incremental update, quite likely created by a signing process, considering the contents of object 34. But that signing process appears to have gone wrong, an **adbe.x509.rsa_sha1** signature with a `null` **Cert** is invalid, so quite likely the best repair option would be to truncate the PDF at the start of the last incremental update.